# How to trick an init script into returning 0

Tags: bash, grep, init-script, init, exit

I have a init script which is poorly designed because it does not conform to the [Linux Standard Base Specifications](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html)

The following should have an exit code of 0 if running, and 3 if not running

```
service foo status; echo $?
```

However because of the way the script is designed, it always returns a 0. 
I can not fix the script without a significant rewrite (because service foo restart is dependent on service foo status).

How could you work around the issue so that `service foo status` returns a 0 if running, and a 3 if not running?

What I have so far:

```
root@foo:/vagrant# service foo start
root@foo:/vagrant# /etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep "up and running"|wc -l
1
root@foo:/vagrant# /etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep "up and running"|wc -l;echo $?
0 # <looks good so far

root@foo:/vagrant# service foo stop
root@foo:/vagrant# /etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep "up and running"|wc -l
0
root@foo:/vagrant# /etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep "up and running"|wc -l;echo $?
0 # <I need this to be a 3, not a 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are piping the `grep` output to `wc` and `echo $?` would return the exit code for `wc` and not `grep`.

You could easily circumvent the problem by using the `-q` option for `grep`:

```
/etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep -q "up and running"; echo $?
```

If the desired string is not found, `grep` would return with a non-zero exit code.

EDIT: As suggested by [mr.spuratic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/31352/mr-spuratic), you could say:

```
/etc/init.d/foo status | /bin/grep -q "up and running" || (exit 3); echo $?
```

in order to return with an exit code of `3` if the string is not found.

`man grep` would tell:

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
          immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
          error was detected.  Also see the -s  or  --no-messages  option.
          (-q is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: To complete the answer: `... | grep -q && (exit 0) || (exit 3)` . This sets the exit code as required.

Comment: @mr.spuratic Nice.  Didn't think about that.  However, `&& (exit 0)` is redundant since a match would imply that `grep` returns with an exit code of `0`.